# Bluetooth terminal app (interface BT device to Android via SPP)?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Trying to get my custom Bluetooth device to be read by my Android phone.  So far, the device is sending data continuously, and I can receive it on a PC with a BT interface running SPP and hyperterminal.

Now changing the PC to my Evo, I installed [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) but it won't connect to my phone.  Found a few SPP terminal emulator apps in the market, but those seem to be based off Bluetooth Chat and also won't connect.  However, Amarino on the same phone connects to the same bluetooth device properly (but that is not a terminal program).

I'm just getting started with Android programming, so not sure where to go from here.  I don't see much docs on how the Bluetooth API works.  Anyone know where I can get info on this?  Or perhaps some other terminal program that will work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and the problem was the UUID.  There's a mention of this in the android developer documentation.

Find this is BluetoothChat.java:

```
// Unique UUID for this application
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
```

and change it to this (i'm using a bluetoothMate from sparkfun.com):

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

This is the standard UUID for SPP/RFCOMM things, which I got from the google developer docs. It worked for me, good luck